# Singleton pattern for database.

Tags: java, singleton

I would like to know if using singleton pattern for my databaseHelper.java class, which have all database related operations i.e (Crud) is a good idea or not? I want to minimize my database hit and memory usage. I use c3p0 i.e connection pooling.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, this is an awful idea for too many reasons.

I suggest you run a simple google search, and even here to find out why. No point in spaming this site.

For example:

- [Is it OK to have singleton DAO objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937548/is-it-ok-to-have-singleton-dao-objects)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516230/is-it-ok-to-make-a-dao-class-as-singleton
- [Singleton Design Pattern: Pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448393/singleton-design-pattern-pitfalls)
- [Alternatives for the singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171291/alternatives-for-the-singleton-pattern) (C# but you can get the idea)

Try looking at the [solutions provided by the Spring framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-data-tier.html). It would give you a much better starting point.