# Global instance of an object

Tags: java, class, singleton, jung

Actually , I use [jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net)  library to construct my hyper graph.

I want to use only one instance of hyper graph all over my application so that I can't access it and mofify it from any class in my application (to add vertex, to add a hyperEdge, etc.).

It is possible ?

I try to use the singleton pattern but as far as I read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons/138012#138012) it is not a good choice.

Comment: Why would Singleton not be a good choice for this? Can you please update the link?

Comment: It's not that the Singleton itself is so much of a bad choice - just what it represents. The idea of having something accessible throughout your entire application means that it is essentially a global variable. When something goes wrong and you have to debug your program, you now have to check _all_ of your program because any class could have modified your graph. You might want to rethink if every part of your program actually needs access to your graph.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is quite good [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/162090/68969), I'd probably favour an Interface and Implementation but you could still use a Singleton for example:

```java
public interface GraphSource {

    public Graph getGraph();
}

public enum DefaultGraph implements GraphSource {

    INSTANCE;

    private Graph<String,String> graph;

    {
        graph = new SparseGraph<String,String>();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Graph getGraph() {
        return graph;
    }

}

public class MyClass {

    public MyClass(GraphSource source) {
        Graph myGraph = source.getGraph();
    }
}
```

But I'd avoid:

```
public class MyClass {

    GraphSource source = DefaultGraph.INSTANCE;

    public MyClass(GraphSource source ) {
        Graph myGraph = source.getGraph();
    }
}
```

As it would be hard to Stub or Mock the graph for testing.  For a large application I'd consider using [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) but this would be overkill for a small application if you are not familiar with it.