# Alternative to using a Singleton or AppDelegate for global data storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, solid-principles

I have an app that needs access to a set of user data that can't be stored on disk. My typical approach in the past would be to create a singleton to hold this data with a concurrent queue for each property to make data reads/writes thread safe.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to do this without the use of Singletons or storing a reference to my user data in my AppDelegate.

Comment: What do you have against writing to files? What do you have against singletons?

Comment: One of the requirements is not saving data to disk for security reasons.

Comment: @Rob I am trying to avoid the use of globally accessible data. Trying to come up with a way to use DI instead. Maybe a framework like Typhoon will work.

Comment: @rob Ian MacDonald asked what I had against writing things to disk.

Comment: I might refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/a/162090/1271826, which quotes http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-singleton/

Comment: @rob So essentially creating getting rid of the static sharedInstance and saving a copy of the class in the App Delegate.

Comment: And passing it to objects that need it, making the relationship explicit, making it easier to unit test, etc. Notably, not letting any any old object sneak in and use/mutate it, but passing reference to those classes that really need it.

Answer (score -1):

NSUserDefaults sounds like what you're looking for. According to [Apple's documentation,](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) "The NSUserDefaults class provides a programmatic interface for interacting with the defaults system. The defaults system allows an application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences." You can use NSUserDefaults in a global manner.

To do this, you need to first create an NSUserDefaults object:

```
NSUserDefaults *myAppDefaults = [NSUserDefaults myAppDefaults];
```

To save data to the defaults system, you would do something similar to the line below:

```
[standardDefaults setObject:@"Smith" forKey:@"lastName"];
```

Finally, you can retrieve your data from the defaults system by storing it in a variable. The line below shows how to set an NSString to be the value you originally stored:

```
NSString *lastName = [standardDefaults stringForKey:@"lastName"];
```

Comment: How is this better than singletons? If anything, it's much, much worse. It doesn't address the issues that one might have with singletons, but rather just introduces a bunch of other issues.

Comment: In addition, I can't store user information to disk.