# Keep reference to object from many places in code

Tags: java, reference

I'm wondering about the best solution (maybe pattern) to this problem:
I have 2 classes that have reference to the same object

```
class A {
    ...
}
class X {
    A objectA;
}

class Y {
    A objectA;
}
```

the problem is how to keep these reference even when one class X or Y assingn new object.
For example

```
class Y {
    A objectA;
    private void doSomething(){
          objectA = new A();  
    }
}
```

at this point the object X has deprecated reference, but I would like it to be aware of this change.
Passing references to each other is unacceptable, so object X can not be aware of object Y.

EDIT:
This pattern can exist in my appliaction more than once so I can't use Singleton

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping a direct reference to `A` in `X` and `Y`, store the object `A` in another class (for example `ObjectStorage`) which both `X` and `Y` can access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `singleton design pattern`.

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(patron_de_conception)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the obejct then why are you assigning the new object to the same reference. Why don't you create a new reference for new object.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key tenets of OOP is that you should try to create loosely coupled objects that interact with one another. In your example, both classes X and Y are tightly coupled to class A.  This is not necessarily a bad thing, but it's always worth asking yourself whether both classes need a member variable (objectA).  If the answer to that is yes, then there's a 2nd question is also worth asking: Do both class X and class Y need a reference *to the same object instance* of class A?

Quite often the answer to this question is no. In other words, it's not at all uncommon to see more than one class with a dependency on a common class, but there's no requirement that each of these need a reference to the same instance of that common class.

If the answer to this question is yes, however, then you have some options. A singleton is one option, but there are often other, better alternatives -  [Are there any viable alternatives to the GOF Singleton Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162042/are-there-any-viable-alternatives-to-the-gof-singleton-pattern)