# C++ map of string to custom class with generics

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, generics, singleton

I have tried for the past days to solve this issue I have with C++. It may be trivial, but I could not find a solution and searching on the Internet got me nowhere, so I'll ask here.

I have a C++ wrapper `Singleton` class, a superclass and a number of subclasses. I need the the instances of the subclasses to be singletons, and so I used the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091314/singleton-and-abstract-base-class-in-c) as it is the one fitting my needs the most. I need a map to act as a register from a string to the correct subclass. To make it concrete, here is the code:

```cpp
// The Singleton class
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T* Instance()
    {
        if (s_instance == NULL) { s_instance = new T(); }
        return s_instance;
    }
protected:
    static T* s_instance;
}

// Superclass
class MySuperclass
{
public:
    inline LPCSTR GetName() { return m_name; }
    
    virtual ~MySuperclass() { }
protected:
    LPCSTR m_name;
    
    MySuperclass(LPCSTR name) { m_name = name; }
}

// Example subclass
class MySubclass : public MySuperclass
{
    // subclass stuff
}
```

Now, I have tried a number of things, let me show all that I have tried:

```cpp
// Where the problems begin
class MyRegister
{
public:
    static void Register()
    {
        Singleton<MySubclass> mySubclassSingleton;
        LPCSTR name = Singleton<MySubclass>::Instance()->GetName();
        s_classes.insert(std::make_pair(name, mySubclassSingleton));
    }
private:
    static std::unordered_map<LPCSTR, Singleton<MySuperclass>> s_classes;
}
```

This is the version I'm stuck with and it gives an error on the `insert` saying:

`E0304  no instance of overloaded function "std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::insert [with _Kty=LPCSTR, _Ty=Singleton<MySuperclass>, _Pr=std::less<LPCSTR>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const LPCSTR, Singleton<MySuperclass>>>]" matches the argument list`

I have tried using `std::pair` instead of `std::make_pair`, changed the definition of the map to:

```cpp
template <class T : public MySuperclass>
std::unordered_map s_classes<LPCSTR, Singleton<T>> s_classes;
```

But to no avail, as the first resulted in the same error (also using the `[]` operator gave me issues with `[name]` as `no operator matches these operands`) and the second results in type errors.

As it stands, I need the classes to be singletons, and to ensure that they are singletons, and I need a register that links a unique string identifying the class to its singleton. Can anyone either explain why this is impossible or if there is something like Java's `<? extends MySuperclass>` in C++ that can work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
template <class T : public MySuperclass>
std::unordered_map s_classes<std::string, Singleton<T>> s_classes;
```

is not valid C++.
But you could simply make a `std::unordered_map<std::string, MySuperclass*> s_classes`.
It's not necessary for our lookup map to know about the `Singleton` pattern, it just needs to map onto a pointer to the corresponding subclass. We must use `std::string` or `std::wstring` as a key, because otherwise pointer comparison would be used between keys, not string comparison. Alternatively, we could provide a custom comparison operator.

The `Singleton` itself can also be simplified. `static` local variables are initialized upon the first use of the function, which is exactly the behavior that we want.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
    static T *Instance()
    {
        static T instance{};
        return &instance;
    }
}
```

Our previous use of `new` would have been a memory leak anyways, since `delete` was never called.

Now, we can also update or `MyRegister` accordingly.

```cpp
class MyRegister
{
public:
    static void Register()
    {
        MySubclass *instance = Singleton<MySubclass>::instance();
        s_classes.emplace(instance->GetName(), instance);
    }
private:
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, MySuperclass*> s_classes;
}
```

Comment: Technically the Meyer's singleton pattern is just as much of a "memory leak" as OP's method; both objects will live until the application exits.  I wouldn't really consider it to be a leak since singletons by design are not meant to be deleted.

Comment: @0x5453 that's not true. If you don't call `delete`, the destructor is not called and depending on it is UB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9921320/5740428 . However, it is guaranteed that objects 
 with `static` storage duration will have their destructors called upon `return` from `main` or `exit()`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2204628/5740428

Comment: UB if you rely on side effects from the destructor, which is defaulted in this case.  But in general you are correct and that is an important distinction to make.

Comment: Thanks @JanSchultke! Tried and worked perfectly fine. Also thanks for the explanation and the upgrade of the Singleton patttern!!!