# Properly using the singleton design pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I'm running a server which on occasion has to search what a client queries. I'd like to write the client query to disk for records, but I don't want to slow down the search anymore than I have to. (The search is already the bottleneck...)

So, when the client performs a search, I'm having the client's thread send a message to a singleton thread, which will handle the disk write, while the client thread continues to handle the client's requests. That way, the file on disk doesn't run into sync issues, and it doesn't slow the clients experience down.

I have a conceptual question here: is the singleton appropriate in this case? I've been using the singleton design pattern a little too much in my recent programming, and I want to make sure that I'm using it for its intended use.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without seeing your overall architecture.  There are drawbacks to the singleton pattern (causes unit-testing difficulties, etc.), it's up to you to determine whether they're relevant or not...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Oli; I've read about the unit-testing difficulties but didn't understand the overall implications. Why is avoiding global state of such importance? For instance, if there's only one file on disk which a program writes to, doesn't one want to make sure it can't be accessed at the same time by different parts?

Comment: the existence of global state can make it difficult to inject dependencies (this is the basis of [mock testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)).  Watch this talk for more details: http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/11/clean-code-talks-global-state-and.html.

Comment: What language are you using? How does using a Singleton help with sync issues & not slowing the experience down? Is a separate process fired to handle this?

Comment: Woops! Sorry about that Buckley. I added some more information about the issue. Let me know if it's more intelligible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some specific legitimate uses for singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080614/what-are-some-specific-legitimate-uses-for-singletons)

Comment: Yep, thanks Somebody. Essentially, what I'm trying to do is what they're calling "The Logger". That makes sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [On Design Patterns: When to use the Singleton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-to-use-the-singleton)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is definitely overused and comes with its share of [difficulties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Drawbacks) (unit-testing is the canonical example), but like everything in design, you need to weigh the pros and cons for your specific scenario. The singleton pattern does have its uses. There are options that may allow you to get the singleton behaviour, while alleviating some of the inherent issues:

[Interception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647107.aspx) (often referred to as aspect oriented programming, though I've seen debate that they are not exactly the same thing... can't find the article I read on this at this time) is definitely an option. You could use any combination of construction injection, the [decorator](http://geekswithblogs.net/dsellers/archive/2006/09/06/90450.aspx) pattern, an abstract factory and an [inversion of control container](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). I'm not up on my Java IoC containers, but there are some .Net containers that allow automatic interception (I believe Spring.Net does, so likely Spring (Java) has this built in). This is very handy for any type of cross-cutting concerns, where you need to perform certain types of actions across multiple layers (security, logging etc.). Also, most IoC containers allow you to control lifetime management, so you would be able to treat your logger as a singleton, without having to actually implement the singleton pattern manually.

To sum it up. If a singleton fits for your scenario (seems plausible from your description), go for it. Just make sure you have weighed the pros and cons. You may want to try a different approach and compare the two.