# Realtime use of static member of declaring class inside class

Tags: c++, static-members

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517609/why-is-a-class-allowed-to-have-a-static-member-of-itself-but-not-a-non-static-m/8517644#8517644) question on SO and wondered where this kind of code can actually be used in the real time example.

```
struct a
{
    static struct a b;
};


int main()
{
    a::b;

    return 0;
}
```

Also what is the significance of `a::b;` 
Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such code can be used in implementation of the Singleton pattern. Here, one instance of type `a` is declared; if other instances are somehow forbidden, it is the singleton. In practice, however, i recall, they usually use less confusing syntax.

And, as for `a::b`, it does nothing useful. It just shows the name of the instance. A more useful example would be this:

```
struct a
{
    static struct a b;
    int data;
};

a a::b = {9};

int main()
{
    int stuff = a::b.data;
    printf("%d\n", stuff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A class whose number of instances that can be instantiated is limited to one is called a singleton class. Thus, at any given time only one instance can exist, no more. We can implement that through static methods. I do not understand how making the static object of own class helps in achieving that

Comment: @CppLearner The definition of `a::b` can be placed at a predefined address by the linker (this has to do with memory-mapped access to hardware)

Comment: Thanks, I just saw below code from [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593324/c-singleton-class which confirms your explanation. `class MySingleton
{
    public:
        static MySingleton &getInstance()
        {
            static MySingleton instance;            
            return instance;
        }
    private:
        MySingleton();
        ~MySingleton();
};`