# C#: Differences between Singleton and Static Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, class, static, singleton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between static class and singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)

I'm thinking about the choice between Static classes and Singleton pattern on C#.

Do you know how static classes are created?
In particular, I would know if a static class is unique during program execution and what are pro or cons against Singleton pattern.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This has been asked several times before, latest *yesterday*. Searching before asking is a good rule :)

Comment: I love the "Related" sidebar below the adds. It helps a lot finding duplicates. This one in particular, is full of them. And there's also the auto-search-before-asking feature, that after you type the title of your question shows you similar questions. With this exact title it shows the same 61-upvotes question I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static class can not be instanciated.
A singleton can be instanciated once.

[Discussion about the use of the Singleton pattern](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/singleton-considered-stupid)

[And more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831/singletons-good-design-or-a-crutch)