# MVC in Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller

I'm having troubles understanding if I'm properly implementing the MVC pattern in an iPhone app. In my app I have views, view controllers and models. The view controllers manage the interfaces, navigate to other view controllers, set variables to other view controllers and models, and communicate with the models. But this way, am I correctly following the MVC pattern? Don't I miss a model controller?

Another question: I have a User Model that I need to have access to in almost every models and some controllers. Would it be correct to define it as a variable in the appDelegate? I'm all the time reading that this is a bad practice, but I don't see why in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Global objects

All non trivial code has bugs, and they are harder to track if you use dumb global objects. By "dumb" I mean generic objects from the API that lack a single point of access in case you need to log, validate, [key-value observe](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), and notify, changes. You can wrap the global object in a class to route everything through your own accessors.

Some say using globals at all gets you into a bad habit. Others say it depends on the size of your code because it is a trade between development speed and complexity.

The appdelegate is a Singleton, so this discussion is related: [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons) and [Singletons: good design or a crutch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831/singletons-good-design-or-a-crutch).

#### MVC

Apple talks about it in [Cocoa Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1) and [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1).

> One can merge the MVC roles played by
>   an object, making an object, for
>   example, fulfill both the controller
>   and view roles—in which case, it would
>   be called a view controller. In the
>   same way, you can also have
>   model-controller objects. For some
>   applications, combining roles like
>   this is an acceptable design.

Is your design complex enough to need a model controller? Whatever your decission is, suffering the consequences will teach you a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

A design pattern in which the model (any data in your program), the view (what the user sees), and the controller (a layer that handles all interaction between the view and model) are separated in such a manner that modifying either the view or model component of your program has no effect on one another.

The purpose:

The purpose is that later on you may need to change your programs view, and by programming things in this matter you will not have to modify your programs model.  Say for instance Apple comes out with an iPad for which the view is programmed somewhat differently than on the iPhone, but you would like to

Now I received some messages after making the video above, some thanking me for making the concept of MVC sound so simple, and others telling me that I had confused them, and wondering how I could understand any of this stuff.

Well, don’t fret.. I’ve seen arguments all over the place as to what components should be classified in the model, the view, or the controller, and I’ve even seen accomplished "guru authors" mess things up when explaining what goes where, just keep in mind that the key idea here is that you can modify one of these key areas without completely wrecking another key area of your program, and leave the rants to the wannabe coders who like to argue about what exactly what fits what acronym, and MVC is often their target.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. My confusion is that in the view controller I'm at the same time managing the interface (e.g. filling in a tableview) and handling the interaction between the view and model. Is this correct or am I mixing 2 concepts in 1? Btw, you mention in your answer you've made a video about MVC. Can you please post the link?