# Singleton in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I'm learning about Singleton design pattern. I have the following code example:

```
//singleton.hpp
#ifndef SINGLETON_HPP
#define SINGLETON_HPP

class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton& Instance();
private:
    Singleton();
    static Singleton* instance_;
};

#endif
```

and:

```
//singleton.cpp
#include "singleton.hpp"

Singleton* Singleton::instance_ = 0;

Singleton& Singleton::Instance() {
    if (instance_ == 0) {
        instance_ = new Singleton();
    }
    return *instance_;
}

Singleton::Singleton() {

}
```

What I don't understand is the line:

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance_ = 0;
```

What does this line do and how? I have never seen something like this.

Comment: It's just a pointer, initialised to NULL. Or is that not the part you don't understand?

Comment: I'm just curious how can you access a private member like that?

Comment: Make sure you google "Thread Safe Singleton C++" somewhere in your quest.

Comment: It is a _definition_ of static variable, _declared_ in your class.

Comment: Off topic a little, just be aware when you understand it that the Singleton pattern is very frequently used inappropriately

Comment: Just to note, it's usually considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: See [Singletons: Good Design or Crutch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11831/1084416) and [What is so bad about Singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/137975/1084416), amongst many.

Comment: [Singleton: How should it be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance_ = 0;
```

just means

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance_ = NULL;
```

Because it is static variable, you need to declare it in .h file and define it in .cpp file

Comment: Oh, I didn't really check up on static variables enough. That's the answer I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

that is the same as

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance_ = NULL;
```

It's just setting the instance to null at the beginning, so that the first time you grab the Singleton it will new up the Singleton object.

Then from there on out, anytime you try to get the Singleton it will give you the first instantiated object.